# Find $144^3$ mod $213$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

> Find $144^3$ mod $213$

I'm not sure how to solve this.

I know that $213=3\times 71$, which are primes.

And I can find that $144\equiv 0$ mod $3$, and $144\equiv 2$ mod $71$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes. Do I want a solution which is $144^3$ mod $3$ and $144^3$ mod $71$

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$144^3\equiv0\pmod3$ and $144^3\equiv2^3=8\pmod{71}$.

If $x\equiv8\pmod{71},$ then $x\equiv79, 150, $ or $221\pmod{213}$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$144^{\large 3}\bmod\, 3\cdot 71\, =\, 3\:\!\underbrace{\left[\dfrac{\color{#0a0}{144^{\large 3}}}3\!\bmod 71\right]\!=\, 3\:\![\color{#c00}{50}]}_{\textstyle \ \dfrac{\color{#0a0}{2^{\large 3}}}3\,\equiv\, \dfrac{-63}3\,\equiv\,\color{#c00}{-21}}$

Comment: using $\ ab\bmod ac = a(b\bmod c) = $ [Mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242), and trivial mental arithmetic $\ \ \ $